# How to apply float property for tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have designed a html tabs. I applied `float` property to it. The problem is when I minimize browser tabs are not visible properly. Here the my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/vn1Leuq3/

and JavaScript is copied from Internet so can any one tell how this JavaScript works and applying float property? It really helps me.
Here is JavaScript code:

```
tabs = function(options) {

var defaults = {  
    selector: '.tabs',
    selectedClass: 'selected'
};  

if(typeof options == 'string') defaults.selector = options;
var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

return $(options.selector).each(function(){
                            
    var obj = this; 
    var targets = Array();

    function show(i){
        $.each(targets,function(index,value){
            $(value).hide();
        })
        $(targets[i]).fadeIn('fast');
        $(obj).children().removeClass(options.selectedClass);
        selected = $(obj).children().get(i);
        $(selected).addClass(options.selectedClass);
    };

    $('a',this).each(function(i){   
        targets.push($(this).attr('href'));
        $(this).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            show(i);
        });
    });
    
    show(0);

});         
}tabs('nav ul');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supress from nav and ul

```
height: 28px;
```

Add

```
overflow: auto;
```

To your ul element.
That will prevent your tab links to disapear. If you want them to stay in a line, you will need to set to your ul element min-width property like this:

```
min-width: 800px;
```

Comment: no , it appears a scroll bar when I minimize. and it disappears

Comment: The float property is applied in the css, not in the js

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/vn1Leuq3/1/)
  Look my fiddle.

```
nav ul
{
 width:100%;
}
nav ul li
{
 width:20%;
}
nav ul li a
{
  text-align: center;
  width:auto;
}
```

Specify width in percentage. It ll solve your problem.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/vn1Leuq3/4/)

```
    @media all and (max-width:320px)
    {
        li
        {
         width:100% !important;
         border: 1px solid red;
        }
        nav
       {
        height: auto !important;
       }
  }
```

Comment: this is fine but i want when I minimize i want tabs to below one by one.

Comment: U need to use media queries. Google it

Comment: when the screen gets too narrow, the tabs are very "squished" using just a %

Comment: @dandavis Yeah. It ll maintain the design

Comment: good feel means, link should be appear as it was appear before.

Comment: Check my latest demo and change width according to you.

Comment: Learn it :) Google it